# Symfony Redis keeps connecting to localhost instead of defined host in env file

Tags: php, symfony, caching, redis

We have a new Symfony setup with Redis as cache mechanism. We want to connect to a specific host, not the default localhost. On production, the ./bin/console debug:dotenv gives the correct REDIS_HOST. This is configured in our .env and .env.local.php.

The error we get is:

Connection refused: tcp:127.0.0.1/6379

This is our config:

**services.yml**

```
services:
    Redis:
        # you can also use \RedisArray, \RedisCluster or \Predis\Client classes
        class: \Predis\Client
        calls:
            - connect:
                  - '%env(REDIS_HOST)%'
                  - '%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%'
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - '@Redis'
            - prefix: sp_ss_
            - ttl: 1800
```

**cache.yml**

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: 'Redis'
        pools:
            site.cache:
                adapter: cache.app
```

**And our .env file:**

```
APP_ENV=prod
APP_SECRET=****
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=redis://redis.local:6379/messages
REDIS_HOST=redis.local
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_URL=redis://redis.local:6379
```

Answer (score 1):

The Symfony's documentation suggest to use "calls -> connect", but it's used only when you was defined the class as 'Redis'. When you use '\Predis\Client', you need to use the settings bellow:

"**config/services.yaml**"

```yaml
    Redis:
        # you can also use \RedisArray, \RedisCluster or \Predis\Client classes
        class: \Predis\Client
        # See all parameters here: https://github.com/predis/predis/wiki/Connection-Parameters#list-of-connection-parameters
        arguments:
            - host: '%env(REDIS_HOST)%'
            - port: '%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%'
            # uncomment the following if your Redis server requires a password
            # - password: '%env(REDIS_PASSWORD)%'
```

I'm also using the '\Predis\Client' and after to change to 'arguments' the connection was worked here.

For more parameters references, please check this [link (List of connection parameters)](https://github.com/predis/predis/wiki/Connection-Parameters#list-of-connection-parameters).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There might be hidden other **.env** files. May you check out the files list with the following code at the root of your projects? Are there other env files such as **.env.prod**, **.env.local**?

```
ls -lah
```